# MYSQL, is possible add/use a INDEX in QUERY {DESCRIBE/SHOW FIELDS}?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to add/use a INDEX in QUERY {DESCRIBE/SHOW FIELDS}?

I am not searching to solve "No index used in query/prepared statement"

How do I add INDEX to the QUERY

```
DESCRIBE `table`;
```

or

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM `table`;
```

Comment: why do need an index on that littke bit of information, annd no, there will never be an index on that, because it isn't necessary

Comment: It's a silly thing you are asking .. Why would you want to add a key to a table description .. Even if you could, it would be totally useless.  Maybe we're not understanding the context .. Why are you asking this question?  Is it homework?

Comment: **many thanks by read**, in my previous Q I justified point by point, then "somebody" delete my Q. Just I want **add index** because answer using **mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);** is: `Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No index used in query/prepared statement DESCRIBE `table`; in line X...`